how do i get the kali bija mantra out of my head?
i know you're gonna tell me to find a guru but i live in the middle east where there are no gurus, so please tell me if there's someone online who can help me, or if there's a practice i can do to solve this problem:
last year i was looking for mantras on the internet (which i know now is careless) and came across a kali mantra that says "om kring kalilaye namo namaha" and it was intense and made me attached to ma kali, then i heard the bija mantra from that mantra "kring" on a hindu podcast and since then everytime i hear a word with the same letters of that mantra it activates in my body and makes my feels very uncomfortable and irritated and when i hear any other mantra it doesn't feel comfortable because my body is preoccupied by this bija mantra, its effect got less with meditation but it's still affecting my life negatively.

That may be due to dopamine dysregulation. Dopamine is a interest hormone, that attracts our attention towards a thing/person/idea. Once we get enough attention or benefitted out of that concept, we get stuck/bored and there is only repetition. After that, you sense that there is not much creativity or learning and you get bored. This is like the residual electric charges lingering around. So, remove all sources/references to that activity/concept . Pick up a new concept/idea/hobby completely different or closely related. Distraction is an alternative. If you go back in future, you may see the mantra in a different perspective. Every few years, I understand Bhagavad Gita in new perspectives, with new learnings/experiences.
Also, only chanting mantra without an associated activity is like repetition. Inittally it may help with distraction from fear/desperation. For some, it creates anxiety or obsession. You have a murthi, observe rules/wear symbols , do puja, prepare and offer neivedhyam, chant few slokas and understand meaning, include chanting mantra, and complete the activity with consuming prasada. This serves as a meaningful pursuit, because different aspects of skills/procedures are involved. You can introduce variety in  food-flowers-decorations-new slokas-new mantras etc. which will engage your mind in new learnings.
It depends on an individaul, some learn with varied tasks, some want to take one and perfect that task and then move on to another and incorporate the newly mastered one.
P.S: I am not a vedic scholar or any psychologist, just trying to help/analyse.
